# Convex Hull operation not specific enough

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, convex-hull, concave-hull

I have yield data as point values, and I simply want to create the boundary around this layer. I have used the Minimum Bounding Geometry tool and selected Convex Hull to do this, however it maintains the corners as part of the polygon. Is there a way to automatically keep just the boundary of this file? Pictures below.

Here's the point file:

[image]

Here's what Convex Hull gives me:

[image]

And here's what I need to automate:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

There are different ways to create concave hulls in QGIS (= [alpha shapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape), look at [Introduction to Alpha Shapes (pdf)](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ddm/texts/Delaunay/alphashapes.pdf),  K. Fischer 2000 and [On the creation of concave hulls and the various ways of doing that.(alpha-shapes)](https://portailsig.org/content/sur-la-creation-des-enveloppes-concaves-concave-hull-et-les-divers-moyens-d-y-parvenir-forme.html), in French, which I take the figures).

- [Concave Hull](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/concavehull.html) script in the processing toolbox, you can create holes

[image]

- The new [Concave Hull](https://github.com/detlevn/QGIS-ConcaveHull-Plugin) plugin with clusters (if you want)

[image]

- The [PgRouting Layer](https://github.com/anitagraser/pgRoutingLayer) plugin of Anita Graser (underdark), based on PostGIS ([A Closer Look at Alpha Shapes in pgRouting](http://anitagraser.com/2011/09/25/a-closer-look-at-alpha-shapes-in-pgrouting/))

You can also use

- GRASS GIS ([Create concave hull](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Create_concave_hull))

[image]

- OpenJUMP ([Concave hull based on JTS](http://www.rotefabrik.free.fr/concave_hull/) extension)

[image]

- Python only ([The fading shape of alpha](http://sgillies.net/blog/1155/the-fading-shape-of-alpha/) , [Drawing Boundaries In Python](http://blog.thehumangeo.com/2014/05/) or [Alpha shapes in Python](http://thezestyblogfarmer.blogspot.be/search/label/hull), using the [hull](http://www.netlib.org/voronoi/hull.html) C program), examples in my scripts (in French), [concave_hull1.py](https://portailsig.org/content/concavehull1py.html) and [concave_hull2.py](https://portailsig.org/content/concavehull2py.html)

[image][image]

- R spatial with the [alphahull](http://yihui.name/en/2010/04/alphahull-an-r-package-for-alpha-convex-hull/#more-515) package (there is also [alphashape3D](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alphashape3d/index.html), for 3D "concave hulls"): look at my script (in French) [alpha_shape.R](https://portailsig.org/content/alphashaper.html)

[image]

With [alphashape3D](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alphashape3d/index.html)

[image]

- PostGIS ([PostGIS Concave Hull](http://www.bostongis.com/postgis_concavehull.snippet))
- SpatiaLite ( [Delaunay Triangulation, Convex Hull and Concave Hull](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=tesselations-4.0))